# Why does 'systemd' not recognize an alias for etcd?

Tags: alias, systemd

My service depends on [`etcd2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_Linux#Cluster_infrastructure):

```ini
# vim: ft=systemd :

[Unit]
Description=SkyDNS Service
After=docker.service
After=etcd2.service
Requires=docker.service
Requires=etcd2.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
# XXX: Must set HOME in order to make docker load its config file
Environment=HOME=/home/core
Environment=TAG=prd-2020-05-08

TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull project/skydns:${TAG}
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f skydns
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/etcdctl set \
  /skydns/ca/plntr/hosts/%m '{"host":"${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}"}'
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/etcdctl set \
  /skydns/ca/plntr/hosts/%H '{"host":"${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}"}'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '                                           \
  set -ex;                                                         \
  docker run -t --name skydns --net host                           \
    -e SERVICE_IGNORE=true                                         \
    project/skydns:${TAG}                                         \
      -addr 172.17.42.1:53                                         \
      -local "%m.hosts.plntr.ca"                                   \
      -nameservers 8.8.8.8:53                                      \
      -domain plntr.ca.;                                           \
'
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f skydns
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
```

But this fails because a dependency can not start:

```
░░
░░ A start job for unit etcd2.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 5453 and the job result is failed.
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 systemd[1]: Starting etcd - highly-available key value store...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit etcd2.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit etcd2.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 5540.
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/etcd/defa>
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_NAME=ip-172-31-4-62
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: etcd Version: 3.3.25
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: Git SHA: Not provided (use ./build instead of go build)
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: Go Version: go1.18.1
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: setting maximum number of CPUs to 4, total number of available CPUs is 4
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: the server is already initialized as member before, starting as etcd memb>
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 etcd[19508]: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: bind: address already in use
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 systemd[1]: etcd2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit etcd2.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 systemd[1]: etcd2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit etcd2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 14 13:29:06 ip-172-31-4-62 systemd[1]: Failed to start etcd - highly-available key value store.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit etcd2.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit etcd2.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 5540 and the job result is failed.
```

I am curious. The `etcd` service has an alias as `etcd2`, so I suppose [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) should detect that `etcd` has already started, when checking the `etcd2` dependency for `skydns`. Here are my configuration files:

```
$ sudo systemctl list-units --type=service | grep etcd
  etcd.service                                   loaded active running etcd - highly-available key value store
● etcd2.service                                  loaded failed failed  etcd - highly-available key value store
```

/lib/systemd/system/etcd.service

```ini
[Unit]
Description=etcd - highly-available key value store
Documentation=https://etcd.io/docs
Documentation=man:etcd
After=network.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment=DAEMON_ARGS=
Environment=ETCD_NAME=%H
Environment=ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/etcd/default
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/%p
Type=notify
User=etcd
PermissionsStartOnly=true
#ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "GOMAXPROCS=$(nproc) /usr/bin/etcd $DAEMON_ARGS"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/etcd $DAEMON_ARGS
Restart=on-abnormal
#RestartSec=10s
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=etcd2.service                       #<<<--- NOTICE THIS
```

/etc/systemd/system/etcd2.service

```ini
[Unit]
Description=etcd - highly-available key value store
Documentation=https://etcd.io/docs
Documentation=man:etcd
After=network.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment=DAEMON_ARGS=
Environment=ETCD_NAME=ip-172-31-4-62
Environment=ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/etcd/default
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/%p
Type=notify
User=etcd
PermissionsStartOnly=true
#ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "GOMAXPROCS=$(nproc) /usr/bin/etcd $DAEMON_ARGS"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/etcd $DAEMON_ARGS
Restart=on-abnormal
#RestartSec=10s
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=etcd2.service
```

[I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60006587/4632019), `systemd` does not see that configured alias:

```
$ systemctl show -p Id --value etcd.service
etcd.service
$ systemctl show -p Id --value etcd2.service
etcd2.service
$ systemctl show -p Names --value etcd.service
etcd.service
$ systemctl show -p Names --value etcd2.service
etcd2.service
```

How can I configure `systemd`, so it counts `etcd` and `etcd2` as aliases?

Comment: Is your `/etc/systemd/system/etcd2.service` actually a symlink to `/lib/systemd/system/etcd.service` ? The shown contents differ a bit, but it should be a symlink.

Comment: No, It is not a symlink.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob: it would be nice to automatically move topic to related SO site if such mistakes occur.

Comment: @EugenKonkov - You should raise a moderator flag so the question can be migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to systemd's [systemd.unit manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Description), systemd uses symlinks for aliases:

> Units can be aliased (have an alternative name), by creating a symlink from the new name to the existing name in one of the unit search paths

Setting `Alias` config in the `[Install]` section creates also symlinks:

> Unit files may specify aliases through the Alias= directive in the [Install] section. When the unit is enabled, symlinks will be created for those names, and removed when the unit is disabled.

So I would deduct that you have a broken alias configuration. Try to remove the file */etc/systemd/system/etcd2.service* and create a symlink */lib/systemd/system/etcd2.service* that points to */lib/systemd/system/etcd.service* - if that is not already existing.

You should probably keep a copy of the file you are going to remove before you try that solution, just in case, so you can restore it in case something goes really wrong.

Comment: yeah, that was an issue. I found local script which do some changes with `sed`. I added `--follow-symlinks` option to it, so it  [now it does not break symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192017/129967) and `etcd` and `etcd2` are recognized as aliases. Would be nice to see some warning from `systemd` that `Alias` is ignored because of conflicting manual file at `/etc/systemd/system` folder. It will make things more obvious.